# How do I know that $p$ pass through the tangent plane $T_p(S)$?

Tags: differential-geometry

This may be a silly question but I can't prove it.

Let $S$ be a regular surface and $p \in S$.Let **$x$** be a parametrization of $S$. We have that the tangent plane at p is $T_p(S)=dx_p(\mathbb{R^2})$.

My question is, how can I prove formally that $p$ is indeed in $T_p(S)$?

I have no idea of which vector $v$ is such that $p=dx_p(v)$.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're defining $T_p S = dx_p( \mathbb R^2 )$, then this is not true in general, since you have by definition required the tangent plane to pass through the origin. If you want to view $T_p S$ as the classical tangent plane to $S$ at $p$ then you need to use the definition $T_p S = x(p) + dx_p (\mathbb R^2)$. This should make sense - remember that the linear approximation to a function $f$ at $p$ is not just $f(p+x) \approx f'(p)x$, but $f(p+x) \approx f(p) + f'(p)x$.